# Правильное округление в андроиде

Tags: java, android

Как всегда, сделанный пальцем Android-Java, поставил в тупик на ровном месте. Какие методы не перепробовал, какие молитвы и каким святым не произносил, но не могу решить элементарную задачу:

есть long Х1, Х2 ... ХN (время в миллисекундах); 
есть их сумма: Х_сумма.

Как получить значения Y1, Y2 ... YN, где Yi = Xi / Х_сумма,

при этом формат Yi такой: 23.4%, а сумма всех Yi была бы 100.0%, а не плюс/минус несколько процентов, причем чем большее количество Yi, тем дальше от 100.0% результат. Округление по правилам, как нас учили еще в школе.

Comment: Посмотрите :
[https://habrahabr.ru/post/219595/](https://habrahabr.ru/post/219595/)
В каком типе храните результат ( Yi = Xi / Х) ?

Comment: тип неважен, лишь бы правильно считало. Вывод в строку.

Comment: святому BigDecimal я молился, и читал, и использовал метод, предложенный тут: Андроид, финты ушами `http://dolbodub.blogspot.com/2014/04/java.html`. Пока безответно.

Comment: У меня получается потеря точности 10^(-14).Т.е. сумма для 100 значений (результат деления храню в double) получается 99,999999999999987, а нужно 100?

Comment: Проблема здесь не в точности. А в неправильности округления. Ошибка округления на каждом значении приводит к потере 0.1% Глупо же будет, если пользователь смотрит на экран, на котором 2 значения, а их процентное приведение дает в сумме 99.9%. А на 7 значения уже 99.6%. "Ты что, нормально посчитать не можешь", - мысленно помолится разработчику пользователь.

Comment: Т.е. у вас, условно, есть числа `2, 1, 1`, сумма `4`, доли получаются `0.5, 0.25, 0.25`, вы округляете до одного знака, и хотите, чтобы глупая машина как-то за вас догадалась, что надо получить `0.5, 0.3, 0.2`, чтобы у вас в сумме сошлось?

Comment: @zRrr В примере, который Вы привели, Yi будут равны соответственно 50.0%, 25.0% и 25.0 %. Их сумма даст ровно 100.0%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для Вашего случаю достаточно использовать

```
double number = 0.1886717436742374;
//1й вариант округления: 
double number1 =  Math.rint(100.0 * d) / 100.0;
//2й вариант:
double number2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(number).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN).doubleValue();
```

И пример со 2м вариантом:

```
//Задаю количество элементов
int numberOfElements = 16;

//Массив для хранения long значений
long[] longsArray = new long[numberOfElements];
long sum = 0; //Сумма long значений
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
    longsArray[i] = System.currentTimeMillis(); //массив забиваю текущим временем
    System.out.println("i = " + i + "; longArray[i] = " + longsArray[i]);
    sum = sum + longsArray[i];
}
System.out.println("sum of all X is  = " + sum);

//Массив для хранения Xi/Yi значений
double[] yArray = new double[numberOfElements];
double sumOfY = 0; // Сумма всех Xi/Yi
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
    yArray[i] = (double) 100 * longsArray[i] / sum;
    yArray[i] = BigDecimal.valueOf(yArray[i]).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN).doubleValue();
    System.out.println("i = " + i + "; yArray[i] = " + yArray[i]);
    sumOfY = sumOfY + yArray[i];
}
System.out.println("sum of Y is  = " + sumOfY);
```

Comment: Браво! Это уже то, что нужно: ошибка в пределах единицы последнего знака. Только в моем случае надо в первом параметре setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN) указывать единицу, а не двойку. Всех Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, все `X`ы и  `X`сумма типа `long`

попробуйте так

```
double yi = ((Xi*1000) / X_summa) / 10. ; // 1000 для округления до 0,1 процента
```

---

@st-st

Вам нужно хранить и суммировать числа как есть в длинном формате 0,098234235435

а вот отображать можно округлением до 0,01

просто сумму будете брать из первого варианта. по другому никак.

Comment: Ваше предложение дает значение в виде 91.9464688765...%. Как округлить до 1 знака после точки правильно? :)

Comment: @St-st попробуйте этот вариант `double yi = ((Xi*1000) / X_summa) / 10. ;`  в конце десятки точка

Comment: Это уже ближе: формат правильный, но сумма всех Yi начинается с 99.9% и с увеличением количества Yi их сумма уменьшается: при 7 Yi, их сумма уже 99.6%

Comment: @St-st правильно, потому что мы отрезаем часть после запятой. у вас никогда сумма не будет идти. Все равно будет округления. можете этот мусор собрать в последном элементы. если это так нужно.

Comment: Дорогие форумчане, только давайте не будем говорить, что это правильно. Алгебру, нас учили в школе, придумали арабы, и она мерило истины. Андроидному богу надо бы среднюю школу закончить, а потом миллиарды лопатой перелопачивать. Сбрасывать неточность расчетов в какие-то элементы это уже совсем близко с каждением возле разрисованных досок. И почему таких проблем нет в продуктах так критикуемого Майрософта? Специально в Экселе сделал табличку на 20 значений - ошибка все 0,1%.

Comment: @St-st даа у вас кажется проблемы с математикой и вешественными числами. тут андроид не причем. тут вы сами должны школьную математику еще раз почитать. причем тут отображение числа и сумма его в экселе. так как хоть экзел показывает 0.01 он все еще думает о 0.098345345. так что тут у Вас проблема. не в программировании

Comment: Ну я же специально брал отображаемое значение (0,01), а не 0.098345345, которое оно помнит.  Можете с физическим калькулятором, отделенным от Экселя проверить. Ваше утверждение, что сумма никогда не будет идти - ложно. Она не будет ровно 100% только в том случае, если распределение округляемых чисел до 0,5 и после 0,5 будет не равно. Например, 0,33 +0,33 + 0,33. В противном случае, оно всегда будет = 100%. Правильные правила округления придумали не идиоты. Но чтобы на ДВУХ числах при правильном округлении получалось не 100% - это, все же, беда. С таким подходом, станно, что Ангара полетела.

Comment: А в случае равномерного распределения случайных чисел, а не специально подобранных, с увеличением ряда погрешность не будет увеличиваться, всегда будет крутиться вокруг 100%, заходя то в одну сторону, то в другую.